# Android List does not refresh after save button clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an application in which I am trying to refresh the list after I click save button.

The logic is something like this:
1. retrieve the fruit list
2. on the same screen , i can edit/add a new fruit name
3. if I choose to add a fruit name, it brings me some form tags, once entered , I click on save button. 
4. On click on save , it should bring me the activity which retrieves the fruit list(step 1).

```
public class firstActivity extends Activity{
private SQLiteDatabase db;
Button saveButton;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
// some code here
saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedata);
db = openOrCreateDatabase("location.db",
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);


        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fruitName;
                fruitName = fruitName.getText().toString();
    ContentValues fruitContent = new ContentValues();
    fruitContent.put("fruit_name",fruitName);


    if (!(db.isOpen())) {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("location.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    }
    fruitId = (int) db.update(FRUIT_TABLE, fruitContent,"fruit_id=" + f_P_Id, null);
    db.close();
    } else {
    if (!(db.isOpen())) {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("location.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        }
    fruitId = (int) db.insertOrThrow(FRUIT_TABLE, null,fruitContent);

    db.close();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "New Fruit Id:" + fruitId);

    Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
}
}

public class secondActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "cmg");
        setContentView(R.layout.fruitlist);

        /**
         * database code
         */
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("location.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        if (db != null)
            Log.i(TAG, "database created");
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "DAtabase null");

        //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_1);


        Cursor cursor = db.query(tablename, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        int listSize = cursor.getCount();
        final String[] fruit_List = new String[listSize + 1];

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int arrIter = 0;
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Coumn Value:" + cursor.getString(0));
            fruitList[arrIter] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            arrIter++;
        }
        fruit_List[arrIter] = "New Fruit";
        Log.i(TAG, "FruitList:");
        for (int i = 0; i < fruit_List.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Fruit:" + fruit_List[i]);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Count:" + cursor.getCount());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        if (listView != null) {
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruit_List));
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Null");
        }


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        firstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Somehow it does not take me to secondActivity and get the new list. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: rather than v.getContext() you can try firstActivity.this. I am not sure if this will fix your issue, just a suggestion (and how I have created my intents without issue. Have you checked to make sure your secondActivity is included in your Manifest?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't take you to the secondActivity? the application force close or it just stand still and don't open the activity?

Comment: @Mimminito, I tried entering firstActivity.this too, but did not work, I have added secondActivity in Manifest xml file also.

Comment: @Th0rndike, there are no exceptions.. Only thing is, it does not go in second activity. I have put Loggers to check if it is going in second activity.. It brings me the old list instead of new list. Not sure why ...

Comment: @HeshamSaeed, It stand still, but brings me the old list, for example, if I had 3 fruits in my list and try to add new fruit, and then click on save, it shows me previous 3 fruits only instead of showing 4 fruits..

Comment: do you have a logger in the onCreate of the secondactivity and make sure it is running the onCreate again?  Also where do you generate the adapter for the listview?  Where is the data pulled from?

Comment: Have you made sure your new activity has a reference to the new data that you have added the "fruit" from? It looks like you are not passing over the list, and therefore its not being updated.

Comment: @JModi: from where are you fatching that data... if you are using database or what?

Comment: @VaibhavVajani yes, I am using database..

Comment: Ok guys, i have added actual code above.. tell me now..

Comment: @JModi: how are you making list? show that code?

Comment: @VaibhavVajani updated code above...

Comment: Ok Guys, after 3 hours of debugging, I finally found the issue. The problem is you have to finish() the activity each time you start it which I was not doing. So, take care every time you start the activity, please finish (which means destroy/kill) activity too. Thanks all for your effort. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ListView.notifyDataseInvalidate()` will refresh the ListView.

Comment: it does not go in secondActivity itself, then what is advantage of calling ListView.notifyDatabaseInvalidate() ? I am not using List view in firstActivity, its only there in secondActivity. FirstActivity only handles to add a new item and save it ..

Answer (score 0):

When you want to Refresh your ListView Just Remember you will have to insert this Statement.

```
listviewobject.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will automatically Refresh the List.

Comment: it does not go in secondActivity itself, then what is advantage of calling ListView.notifyDatabaseInvalidate() ? I am not using List view in firstActivity, its only there in secondActivity. FirstActivity only handles to add a new item and save it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any exception when you press the save button ?
If not it probably means the click listener is not set properly so make sure you enter the onClick method whenever the save button is pressed.

You can also use the android:onClick attribute to avoid setting click listeners programatically.

In the Button section of your XML layout:

```
android:onClick="onSaveButtonClicked"
```

In your activity:

```
public void onSaveButtonClicked(View view){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you need to know where are you saving the list, and before you enter the second activity, you should have updated this list and access it in the other activity, whether with database / or putting Extra on this intent and then send the whole list to the second activity.

Note: if you are using adapter, use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` function to update the list in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you must use custom adapter.Better and best solution..

[LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom) for your reference

Comment: how is it related to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

@JModi: do something like below...

1) when button is clicked:
   Insert proper entry in database.

2) Make another method say "refreshList()" in which you do the same thing which is you use for making your list.

and call this method after you make entry in database.

--> Use your database and make the list again.
--> Don't forget to use listViewObject.clear() method in start of "refreshList()" method.

I have done it and this method working fine...!!
Hope it will help you...!!
Best of Luck..!!

Comment: @JModi: if you have any further query regarding this, u can ask me.